# ElasticSearch GroupBy Query not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch in dot net framework.The issue i have come across is ,
In Elasticsearch aggregation will return the count of documents for each bucket. Is it posible to get the entire documents on group by column. i need the document that falls in each category that i am grouping by.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so], please read [ask], things like adding your code, what you've tried, any research, error messages, etc will help you get a better answer. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried groupby using aggreration in query along with the search criteria. But using below code i get the count of documents that falls under each category not the document details. .Aggregations(agg => agg .Terms("GroupByClause", avg => avg.Field(x => x.Status) ))

Comment: @Rashmi, you should always support your question with the code you tried, mappings and what are your expecting results. Posting a question like this merely explain peoples what issues you are facing. Please consider editing your question and add supporting code you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. works for me.

public bool GetCountWithGroupby()
        {

```
        var result2 = _client.Search<Car>(s => s
        .Index("vehicles")
        .Type("car")
        .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("my_agg", st => st
            .Field(o => o.Color)
        )));

        var myAgg = result2.Aggregations.Terms("my_agg").Buckets;

        foreach (var bucket in myAgg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"key: {bucket.Key}, count: {bucket.DocCount}");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this. works for me.

public bool GetCountWithGroupby() {
        var result2 = _client.Search<Car>(s => s
        .Index("vehicles")
        .Type("car")
        .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("my_agg", st => st
            .Field(o => o.Color)
        )));

        var myAgg = result2.Aggregations.Terms("my_agg").Buckets;

        foreach (var bucket in myAgg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"key: {bucket.Key}, count: {bucket.DocCount}");
        }
        return true;
    }
```